# Can I add a user group to another group in Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, adduser, groups

I have file named `abc.txt` and 3 groups (`Teacher`, `Staff` and `Student`).
I want to create a group name `CanView`, which allow Teachers and Students to view the file `abc.txt`. Can I add `Teacher` and `Student` to `CanView`?

Comment: "ask" or "add"?

Comment: Add, I fixed after your comment

Answer (score 6):

You have to add each user to the group `CanView`. You can't add a group to the group `CanView`.

But you could use [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

Answer (score 3):

You can "add" them, but first you must read `man adduser`,  `man group` and `man vigr`. On my system, I have added myself to 14 groups. I am not giving you a `do this;do that` style answer, because You must understand what you're doing before you do it, or learn how to recover from doing it wrong. I have tried both ways.

Once you've added them to the `group` file, they must either `logout/login` to apply the new group membership to the session, or use `newgrp CanView` to spawn a single shell with the new group membership active..